# How to scrape data from interactive chart using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a next link which represent an exact graph I want to scrape: https://index.minfin.com.ua/ua/economy/index/svg.php?indType=1&fromYear=2010&acc=1

I'm simply can't understand is it a xml or svg graph and how to scrape data. I think I need to use bs4, requests but don't know the way to do that.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will load HTML like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://index.minfin.com.ua/ua/economy/index/svg.php?indType=1&fromYear=2010&acc=1"
resp = requests.get(url)
data = resp.text
```

Then you will create a BeatifulSoup object with this HTML.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
```

After this, it is usually very subjective how to parse out what you want. The candidate codes may vary a lot. This is how I did it:

Using BeautifulSoup, I parsed all "rect"s and check if "onmouseover" exists in that rect.

```
rects = soup.svg.find_all("rect")
yx_points = []
for rect in rects:
    if rect.has_attr("onmouseover"):
        text = rect["onmouseover"]
        x_start_index = text.index("'") + 1
        y_finish_index = text[x_start_index:].index("'") + x_start_index
        yx = text[x_start_index:y_finish_index].split()
        print(text[x_start_index:y_finish_index])
        yx_points.append(yx)
```

As you can see from the image below, I scraped `onmouseover=` part and get those `02.2015 155,1` parts.

Here, this is how `yx_points` looks like now:

`[['12.2009', '100,0'], ['01.2010', '101,8'], ['02.2010', '103,7'], ...]`

[image]

Comment: Hi Seleme!
Maybe I need to use `url` instead of `html` in `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")` ? Because it says that `html` is undefined.

Even if I change that, next error occurred:
`rects = soup.svg.find_all("rect")`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: All you had to do was to change `data = resp.text` to `html = resp.text`. My bad copy pasting.

Comment: I see, thank you! How I can extract each date and value from this list into two separate columns?

Comment: `[x[0] for x in yx_points]` will give you dates. `[x[1] for x in yx_points]` will give you values.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import re

#First get all the text from the url.
```

url="https://index.minfin.com.ua/ua/economy/index/svg.php?indType=1&fromYear=2010&acc=1"

```
response = requests.get(url)

html = response.text

#Find all the tags in which the data is stored.

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

texts = soup.findAll("rect")

final  = []

for each in texts: 

    names = each.get('onmouseover')
    try:
        q = re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", names)
        final.append(q[0])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

#The details are appended to the final variable
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed! I tried this code but `final` is empty anyway.

Comment: Hi can you try it again, the url was changed in last code.

Comment: Well now it works, thanks!
Do you know where I can learn more about web scraping? What knowledge is required to do successful web scraping?

Comment: I guess instead of going online for learning, use the documentation of libraries which you use. The best scraping modules are selenium and requests. When we learn something by facing errors then you get a lot of grip on the concept and search all your doubts on google, the world's biggest search console has all the data of machine and their languages.